# How to send a scheduled email based on a date made by the user?

Tags: laravel, date, email, input

I need help on how to automate an email that sends a week before the user's indicated date. For example, a user inserts a record wherein he enters a date, and I want to send him an email reminder one week before his set date. How can I do that in laravel? Thank you! I'm hoping for a quick way since I am on a deadline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling). It's fairly easy to implement and it will do the job here.

First, create a [command](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-commands):

```
php artisan make:command SendEmail //Call it as you wish
```

Then, inside the handle() method, you write all the logic for sending emails. For example:

```
public function handle()
    {
        $users = User::get();
        foreach($users as $user){
            if(Carbon::parse($user->reminded_date)->diffInDays(Carbon::now()) == 7){ //Or however your date field on user is called
                //Send an email
            }
        }
    }
```

For date comparison, I used [Carbon's](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) diffInDays() method. You can of course use something else if you don't want carbon.

After you completed your email logic, now you need to create a schedule for this command to run automatically on set interval. You do this in `App\Console\Kernel` class, in the schedule() method. For example:

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')->daily();
```

This line will make your command run every day. If you don't want it to run daily, here's the list of all the [schedule frequency options](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options)

The 'emails:send' name the name of your command:

```
protected $signature = 'emails:send';
```

If you need any more details or help, let me know.

Comment: The `make:command` command will generate all the necessary classes you need for this. You don't need any controller code. This class will be located in `App/Console/Commands` directory

Comment: The `$signature = 'emails:send'` goes to the top of your newly created command, there will already be a placeholder for the name. You can name it whatever you want, it doesn't have to be named after the class name

Comment: Okay will try it now! thank you!

Comment: So this should send an email to me if I sign up with a new user right now that enters a date of July 12?

Comment: No, it wouldn't send it immediately. The command will run later (depending on how you configured your schedule) & then it would send it if the condition is right

Comment: Hello! I would like to kindly ask if this logic you sent will send duplicate emails to those who already received them? Thank you!